# cakephp model: field vs. set method

Tags: cakephp, model

In my code, I'm setting fields of my model with some set calls, e.g.

```
$model->set('field','value');
```

If I understood correctly, this sets the field values in the `$model->data` array.
Immediately after (i.e. same request, but different parts of the code), I would like to access those fields to process them further. I thought this would be possible with:

```
$value = $model->field('field');
```

But that doesn't work, because (as I found out by looking at the code) `field()` is querying the table, but does not use the `$model->data` array. Now my question(s):

1. What would be the "correct" way to read field values again from a model that were just set by `$model->set(...)` but not yet saved to the table? Access `$model->data` directly?
2. Is it necessary to call `$model->save()` first to be able to access field values again?
3. I feel it would be consistent to have a method to set and retrieve field values symmetrically without the need to save in between. Does cakephp feel the same? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `$model->data` to access the current data in the model that is to be saved. Like you said, `field()` does a query. To modify data before saving, you can use the `Model::beforeSave()` callback or modify the data before setting the data for the model.
2. If you mean access the in another request, yes you have to save. If you mean access the data in the current request before you save, no. See #1 on how to access/change data.
3. Unnecessary, see #1.

Comment: Thanks, tigrang. Following your suggestions, I solved it by adding the following function to my `app_model.php`:
`function get($field=null) {
  return $this->data[$this->alias][$field];
 }`.

So I have a shortcut for the lengthy `data` access and a nice counterpart for the `set` function.